# Moving VM from Virtualbox to Hyper-V: networking issues

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, debian, virtualization

I've set up a Debian LAMP stack using [this tutorial](http://jtreminio.com/2012/07/setting-up-a-debian-vm-step-by-step/). Now I want to switch over to Hyper-V, but the networking won't work. Here's what I've done:

1. I've added a Virtual Switch using my external LAN network card in Hyper-V.
2. I've added a Legacy Network Adapter to the Debian VM and set it up to use the correct Virtual Switch.

This results in seeing an eth2 connection that's unconnected and won't connect when trying. **The goal is obviously an eth1 that's bound to my host's network.** How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a second switch, this needs to be an external switch and has to bound to network card that is on your local network.

Then you need to assign each network card to a different virtual switch. This should allow you to achieve what you want.

Comment: Can you clarify what the full virtual switch/network card combo would be? I've created a Virtual Switch for every network card and a network card in the VM for every Virtual Switch, but no luck.